# PHP: Get textbox value from HTML input tag

Tags: php, html

I got a very simple problem and I've searched for it for hours. But I just don't fix my error... I try to get the value of my textbox (I know, there are lots of posts but no one of them could've helped me).

I got this `HTML` code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Enter your zip code" style="width:250px;" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And this is `PHP` code #1 I tried:

```
<?php
    $textboxValue = $_POST['address'];
    echo $textboxValue;
?>
```

This doesn't work and I don't know why. After trying this, I found another code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $textboxValue = $_POST['address'];
        echo $textboxValue;
    }
?>
```

This doesn't seem to work. Like the other one.

Is there an error or why is the `$textboxValue` not displayed when I call it with `echo`?

Comment: Are you actually submitting to the correct PHP file?

Comment: It may happen if you are trying to access post variables in another file. mention your form action file and a file where you written your above mentioned code

Comment: you are not provided name for submit button sset name as submit

Comment: It should submit to itself. So I thought `action=""` will do this?

Comment: try ``var_dump($_POST);`` before defining ``$textboxValue`` value and see what is going on.

Comment: Set the action to the form. Isset() function checks if $_POST[''] is set. Also, name your the input type with name="submit". Use var_dump to dump result of $_POST['address'].

Comment: if your form and a php code are in a same file than there do not seems any problem. Post your complete code here along with file name

Comment: set `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['php_self']; ?>"`

Comment: I got this now: `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ var_dump($_POST['address']); }` and `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" and <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />` - But when I hit the button it doesn't display anything...

Comment: @Pranavc Do ***not*** do this unless you're keen on HTML injection.

Comment: Is the file an actual php file, does php work at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please give the form an action!

And you have to name the submit button submit:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Otherwise `isset()` will return false.

Comment: I now got `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"` and `<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />`

It still doesn't work :/

Comment: Yes it is... That's why I think it's strange

Comment: Hm..what's your file named? $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] should work, but please try it with the action="yourfile.php"

Answer (score -1):

I found the error. In my file I had a `return = false;` so he couldn't execute the `$_POST` method. But thanks for all your help :)

Comment: I can't see any return in your code above. That's why you always should show the whole code.

Comment: Ok..but the solution of the code above is the answer above, because the name="" was missing. So accept the answer, please so that others not search for an return = false which doesn't exist